# What is a digitally controlled SPDT switch that passes an analog signal?

Tags: switches

I thought I found what I was looking for when I found out what an "analog switch" was, but they appear to have a buffer in it, which would convert it to a digital signal. I want to pass an analog signal through. How would I do this?

Comment: Most analog switches do not have buffers and are bidirectional.

Comment: @Evan I looked at a lot of analog switch datasheets and they all had buffers at their inputs.

Comment: The "buffer" may be on the logical input that *controls* the analog switch. Include in your question an example part # that you think is appropriate.

Comment: I hate datasheets. Thanks to everyone for helping me correct my stupid mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'm dumb. It turns out the "IN" pin is actually the control pin, and the "COM" pin is the actual input. I had mixed the two up this entire time. I ended up going with the [MAX4544](http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Maxim-Integrated/MAX4544CPA+/) chip because I only needed one switch and it did exactly what I needed. Thanks to all!

Answer (score 2):

One of the simplest types is the CD4053 IC. It does not have buffers on the analog inputs.

[image: CD4053 triple 2:1 analog switch]

It has 3 SPDT analog switches in one package, each with a separate control signal.

It requires a power supply that can span up to 18v.  The signal must be between these supply rails (i.e. less than the positive supply and greater than the negative supply)

This device has been around for more than 40 years but there are many similar variants.

Answer (score 2):

The only analog switches I am aware of that behave as you suggest are designed for signals such as video.

For ordinary relatively low-frequency signals that are always positive or in a range such as +/-5V or +/-3.3V, you can use [CD4053](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4052b.pdf) type analog switches. If the signal is in the 0-5V or +/-2.5V range, you can use HC4053 type switches.

If the signals are more like +/-15V range you can use something like an [ADG5419](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADG5419.pdf) (there are **many** variations in the ADG*** series).

The above-mentioned switches generally include level shifting so that a logic signal from 0-5V (say) can control a signal in the range +/-5V. When off the switch has a bit of leakage current and capacitance. When on the switch behaves like a resistor which varies with the applied voltage. The variation can cause unacceptable distortion under some conditions.

Generally speaking, switches with high voltage capability tend to have more resistance and/or cost more. Some switches have amazingly low series resistance but can only handle a few volts.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for a digital switch that can route an analog signal. Here is an example
[TS3A5223](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ts3a5223.pdf)

Depending on your requirements you will need to find one that fits your need and budget.

PS: Since I cannot comment yet I will place it as an answer